# Установка сертефиката для https

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Имею проблему, при первом запуске Windows 10, загружаю файл по https, но вылезает ошибка, что не хватает сертификатов. Я скачал сертификат сайта, но у меня возник вопрос как его установить в C++ Qt. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: не надо загружать никакого сертификата

Comment: Какая конкретно ошибка? Система не может написать "не хватает", обычно она пишет что-то более внятное

Comment: SSL error:  The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found

Comment: Если не секрет, скажите адрес сайта (можно без ссылки на файл)

Comment: https://syncwoia.com/#/

Comment: Издатель ISRG Root X1. Возможно, вам пргодится что-то вроде этого https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69427667